# ssh opengl error: X Error of failed request BadRequest

Tags: opengl, ssh, x11-forwarding

The remote pc is a Ubuntu 12.04 (precise) 64-bit with an NVIDIA graphics card and driver (version current-updates) and the local is a macbook-air with an Intel HD graphics 3000 running Mac OS X Lion 10.7.5

My goal is to be able to run an openGL application that currently fails with `X Error of failed request BadRequest`. A (black) window appears during one millisecond, then closes and the X error appears on the terminal.

glxgears opens but the gears move so slowly that at first I thought it was a static image.

glxinfo output:

```
name of display: localhost:10.0
display: localhost:10  screen: 0
direct rendering: No
(etc)
```

I've tried both with `ssh -X` and `ssh -Y` and it fails either way.
Any pointer to how can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using indirect OpenGL, which is tunneling the GL commands through ssh. It only supports an old subset of OpenGl (iirc ~version 1.3).

If you want to use the Linux GPU VirtualGL will help you do so.

Comment: Another possible method, which I use with much success is is using Xpra on the remote machine, where the Xpra server is configured to use a "regular" X server on the target GPU. Of course that one GPU is no longer available to the users on the remote machine.